# Error while import data from UserDefaults using @State in swiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, userdefaults

I have encountered this strange and unusual mistake, which is appearing for the first time! Where the error says:

> No exact matches in call to instance method 'appendInterpolation'

The code is:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Home_screen: View {
    @State private var username = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "username")
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(username)") //Error here
        }
    }
}

struct Home_screen_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Home_screen()
    }
}
```

And this is image for Explain:
[The image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwwf3.png)

Comment: Your `username` is an optional. You will need to provide a non-optional value for it to work.

Comment: Try username.wrappedValue.

Comment: `Text(username ?? "unknown")` or whatever you want to display if there is no entry in `UserDefaults`. Or use `@AppStorage`